# SMART Power On hours interpretation

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

i have system with 5 SSD drives and Power-On Hours attribute is different between all drives; one says 398hrs and other four say 17hrs, but all indicate similar power-on cycle count. Why is that..., also looking at attached SMART result is drive sda failing...

[image]

Comment: Non system disks power down when not being accessed.

Comment: ...however, that usually does not affect power-on hours. They do not measure when the “rust is spinning”.

Comment: After consulting with https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4132/what-are-the-rules-for-diagnosis-logfiles-and-is-such-a-question-even-allowed/4135#4135 I gather that it would be more appropriate to attach a text based log file as opposed to the image you've provided above. In addition, it would seem (based on what you've highlighted) that the giant log you've provided is largely unnecessary, and it would likely be better suited to your needs to provide a bare minimum snippet of the logs as opposed to a giant swath of unnecessary information.